# What qualities and skills one must develop to project himself as a dynamic QA manager or Lead?

Tags: qa-role, team-management, management, strategy, qa-process

I would like to know what skills and qualities one must muster to project himself as a dynamic QA Manager or Lead. I often hear the management in my organization telling me that I don't come up with a road map for the team and this is something that they would like in the person leading the QA team. What exactly is a road map and how to prepare one? What other skills (or habits) need to be developed?

Answer (score 5):

There are some qualities a QA Lead/manager should possess like

> - Determining, negotiating and agreeing on in-house quality procedures
> - Knowledge of standards and specifications
> - Customer requirements
> - Investigating and setting standards
> - Ensuring processes
> - Operating staff
> - Writing management and technical reports
> - Manage Client
> - Analyzing training needs for the team
> - Maximize profitability
> - Analyzing and distributing statistical information
> - Monitoring performance
> - Supervising staff

Answer (score 2):

[Road map](https://www.wrike.com/project-management-guide/faq/what-is-a-roadmap-in-project-management/) is a kind of simplified project plan. There are some qualities that I believe one should obtain to be successful manager:

> - You should always know what you talk about. This makes people trust you.
> - You should know what developers talk about. This will let you advocate your qa team deliverables more effectively
> - You should see and understand all the factors which impact on your application quality
> - You should always look for improvements in your and your team's work
> - You should look ahead for several steps. **This is what a road map will help you with**.
> - You should be ready for failures
> - You should be ready to justify your failures (in lot of peoples' minds there is an opinion that QA is only responsible for uncaught bugs).
> - You should be ready to tell the people unpleasant things (sometimes bad things to the good people)
> - You should always be able to explain a complex thing in simple words
> - You should always look for the balance between the scope, resources and time.
> - You should build the process not to be dependent on an individual. That will reduce the project risks.
> - You should look for the balance between your team member goals and project goals.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a must-have is being able to see beyond the QA department. Quality manager is not a Quality-testing manager. Quality starts from the inception, up to customer support.
A GOOD QA manager must let everyone understand that the quality of the product and the service is everyone's responsibility.
Considering testing as the only responsibility of a QA manager is counterproductive.
A bug-free product is only part of the solution, and sometimes is not the most important one.